# Remove PreferredFocusedView tvOS

Tags: focus, tvos

I have a code in Objective C which I have used a PreferredFocusedView Constraints then I wonder how can I remove this later without changing the view,

[image]

when I say I wanna remove it means I wanna remove this virtual places (in green and blue ) totally and not only remove the FocusGuid layout from the view

I already managed to remove the FocusGuide by using

```
MyfocusGuide.preferredFocusedView = [self preferredFocusedView];
```

But still, those goats buttons (green and blue) exist and in action every time I move to their location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I have found is to use the new array `UIFocuseEnvironment` with **tvOS** 10.0 that make it easy for me

```
- (NSArray<id<UIFocusEnvironment>> *)preferredFocusEnvironments  //Called By [self setNeedsFocusUpdate]
{
    if (CONDITION)
    {
        return @[BUTTON1, BUTTON2];
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
}
```